# Error while assigning self to tableview datasource

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift4, nstableview

This is the error Xcode outputs

**Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

I have a viewcontroller that has a tableview and a few buttons; the buttons allow me to insert or remove data. It seems that when I click on Add (which brings up a new viewcontroller via segue as a sheet) the app crashes with the error above. Clicking on remove doesn't have this affect. So it has to do with something regarding the new viewcontroller as a guess. The console doesn't go further into the error other than printing out (lldb)

Here's my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    alarmTableView.dataSource = self //error occurs here
    alarmTableView.delegate = self //if i remove the above line if will occur here too.
}
```

My Viewcontroller which the above viewDidLoad func is embedded lists the protocols I need

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var addAlarm: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var resetDataButton: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet var alarmArrayController: NSArrayController!
    @IBOutlet weak var alarmTableView: NSTableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var deleteAll: NSButton!

    @objc let moc: NSManagedObjectContext

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.moc = CoreDataHandler.getContext()
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationController = segue.destinationController as! AddAlarmViewController
        //pass data to next controller here

    }



    @IBAction func deleteAllAction(_ sender: Any) {

        if (alarmTableView.selectedRow >= 0) {
            if (CoreDataHandler.deleteAllObjectsInEntity(entityName: "Alarm")) {
                //remove from nsarray controller
                for object in alarmArrayController.arrangedObjects as! [Alarm] {
                    print(object)
                    alarmArrayController.removeObject(object)
                }

                alarmTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        else {
            printInfo(str: "There are no alarms to delete")
        }

    }


    /* Response to the remove alarm button  - It removes a selected alarm object from the table */
    @IBAction func resetDataAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if (alarmTableView.selectedRow >= 0) {
            let selectedAlarm = self.alarmArrayController.selectedObjects.first as! Alarm

            alarmArrayController.remove(atArrangedObjectIndex: alarmTableView.selectedRow)

            CoreDataHandler.deleteObjectInEntity(entityName: "Alarm", obj: selectedAlarm)
            alarmTableView.reloadData()
        }
        else {
            //will need a warning or play a sound.
            printInfo(str: "Please select an alarm")
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        printInfo(str: "viewdidload")
        print(alarmTableView)

        if (alarmTableView != nil) {
            printInfo(str: "AlarmTableView Is initialised")
            alarmTableView.dataSource = self
            alarmTableView.delegate = self
        }
        else {
            printInfo(str: "AlarmTableView is not initialised")
        }

    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    func printInfo(str: String) {
        print("ViewController: \(str)")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }
}

class AddAlarmViewController: ViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var closeButton: NSButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.
    printClassInfo(str: "viewDidLoad")
    CoreDataHandler.saveTestData()


}

@IBAction func closeButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismissViewController(self)
}

func printClassInfo(str: String) {
    print("AddAlarmViewController \(str)")
}
```

}

If I remove the lines where the error occurs the app run fine. But I want to override the delegate and datasource and use the functions to further customise the table. I'm also using Cocoa Bindings.

Why am I getting this error?

**Update**

I haven't solved it yet, but i placed a couple of print statements in my viewDidLoad function. It seems that when the app is first loaded, the table view is initialised. But after when I clicked on the Add button, the table view is then set to nil for some odd reason, as if another table view has been initialised. However the data is still visible

Comment: My guess is that your `alarmTableView` is `nil`. Show how you are assigning this variable. If you're using an IB Outlet, check that the outlet is still valid

Comment: can you please shar fully code of this viewcontroller?

Comment: @kbunarjo yep, you're right the alarmTableView is nil. But is that not initialised by the Storyboard? I do have a Referencing Outlet from alarmTableView to the View Controller. Please refer to the updated post for variable assignment

Comment: @Jaydip updated with full code

Comment: Your tableView is nil!! Maybe because it's not connected to outlet.

Comment: @AgentSmith thanks, i got that part but it seems as it is has been initialised and connected to the outlet as I can see data in the table. It's just when I click on the Add button some weird happens to the tableView.

Comment: @bigubosu where is the code of add button?

Comment: @AgentSmith Since i want to open a new view with the add alarm feature, it's currently running via segue. So if you look at the prepare(for segue: sender:) function it runs through there then the viewDidLoad() for AddAlarmViewController will run, and here  I have code to add a few pieces of data, temporarily of course

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166221/discussion-between-bigubosu-and-agent-smith).

Comment: @bigubosu Why does the initial `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` run again after you are done with your `AddAlarmViewController`? Now that don't make no sense for the information you have currently provided.

Comment: @bigubosu What does your `AddAlarmViewController` contain?

Comment: @staticVoidMan updated with my AddAlarmViewController. I'm also using a tutorial from Ray Wenderlich's website as a guide

Comment: @bigubosu Share your project online, let me have a look. Sanitize the code if required.

Comment: @staticVoidMan sorry use the github repository https://github.com/markhmwong/CryptoAlert

Comment: @bigubosu 1. Remove that `viewWillAppear` logic and move it back to `viewDidLoad`. That part was fine. Infact you should simply set the `datasource` & `delegate` through storyboard.

Comment: @bigubosu 2. Data not showing is because you are returning `true` in `tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:)`. This function expects to return `Any?` not `Bool?` so for now just return `nil`. Pay attention to the console logs.

Comment: @staticVoidMan 2. comment out that function tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:). you'll get some data. Sorry i was meddling with the code and forgot to revert it back

Comment: @staticVoidMan :o you're right. Well I don't quite understand it  but I'm gonna keep going. Just a note for others following, the ViewController didn't load again after I clicked the Add button.

Comment: @bigubosu Wait... there's a fix. let me check

Comment: @bigubosu Aahh... what a FUp! Posting an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem:

```
class AddAlarmViewController: ViewController {    
//... 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //...
    }
}
```

Your `AddAlarmViewController` is a subclass of `ViewController` instead of `NSViewController`.

In `AddAlarmViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` you call `super.viewDidLoad()` which basically calls `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`.
**But...** in this case `ViewController` is a new instance as the super class of `AddAlarmViewController` and none of it's properties are initialized.
Whatever it be, it's probably not what you want.

### Solution:

```
class AddAlarmViewController: NSViewController {
//... rest as it is
}
```

Comment: omg.. actually as I was prepping it for github, it asked me to override printClassInfo() I thought that was weird but obviously flew over my head.

Comment: @bigubosu Hah, I was wondering why the `viewDidLoad` was being called so frequently. It was just weird. Well... anyways, now you can continue. Happy coding